# Is there a risk that Apple will not accept me as an applied iPhone Developer (with paid membership)?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

What does it mean that I have to "apply"? Can day say: "No, we don't like your nose. Do something else!"? Did they do that in the past?

I've been investing now two full months worth about 20.000 USD on learning for iPhone programming, and I didn't apply yet...

Comment: 0  vote down
 

Is that "twenty thousand USD"? Oh, my. Is this money that you've actually paid out or just estimated wages for time spent?

Comment: I should add up all of the time I spend watching TV and figure out how much I have invested

Comment: ive invested about 200,000 in team fortress 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've never heard of them rejecting an application for developer license. But I've heard plenty of stories of them rejecting code. That's the much larger risk with Apple's stranglehold on the iPhone marketplace.

Comment: There's also the possibility that only three people will buy your app.  The App Store has outgrown its organization, and there's a whole lot of competition out there.

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for them not to accept you as a iPhone developer.  There is no situation that I know of where they have denied the application provisioning for testing out on the iPhone.  They can and will deny your app submission to the app store in some cases.  Usually those cases include:

- Using copyrighted assets which you do not have a license for
- Competing with one of their apps (mail client was the only one I know of)
- No value added (yet another "flashlight" app - pretty rare)
- Opening the iPhone to scripting attack through download.
- Does not conform to their UI guides

The last of these is the trickiest.  A friend of mine had his app rejected because he used a UI widget in an unexpected way.  This is pretty subjective IMO but they did tell him exactly why they denied it and accepted it when he fixed the issue.

Also about the 20,000,  I can't agree here.  In addition to learning and bettering yourself as a programmer, you are assuming that you would be paid for every off hour you spend learning - not very realistic.

Comment: they've even opposed app-publish when apps contained legally licensed / owned material they sell in the iTunes store (ref. Trey Parker / Matt Stone) -- Sieg Heil, Steve Jobs

Answer (score 0):

Apple has a right to not accept your app at their wish, so you have to take a risk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they could.  That's the risk behind developing for any tightly locked down environment.

Of course in practice they are unlikely to reject you for no reason.

And you're already taking a gigantic risk by investing $20k into iPhone development.  I can't help wondering if this is a saturated market, although there have been a few well publicised success stories, everybody and his dog are now working on a bejeweled clone, and lets face it, even people who buy iphones are going to be looking a reduction in spending on pointless trivia soon with the market the way it is